# How to return an implementation of an interface with interface as return type?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I have an interface:`ISearch<T>` and I have a class which implements this interface: `FileSearch : ISearch<FileSearchResult>`

I have a class `FileSearchArgs : SearchArgs` which has a method to return the a search object:

```
public override ISearch<SearchResult> getSearchObject () 
{ 
   return ((ISearch<SearchResult>)new FileSearch()); 
}
```

This is overridden from:

```
public virtual ISearch<SearchResult> getSearchObject () { return null; }
```

The code would only build if I provided the cast to (ISearch), but it throws an exception at runtime with an unable to cast error. Additionally, a previous iteration did not apply generics to the interface, and thus the method signature of `getSearchObject()` was as follows:

```
public override ISearch getSearchObject() { return new FileSearch();}
```

---

**I know one solution could be to return a base class "Search" instead of an implementation of the interface, but I'd prefer not to do this, and understand why I cannot follow the pattern I previously had.**

Any help, would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to greatly simplify what is going on, so if any clarification is needed, please let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the relationship (if any) between `SearchResult` and `SearchResultSummary`?

Comment: @Jacob - Sorry, was shortening the names, and obviously missed taking out one 'summary' I've fixed it in the post

Comment: That's better.  I assume that `FileSearchResult` also derives from `SearchResult`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to declare you interface like this:

```
interface ISearch<out T> { 
  // ...
}
```

(assuming that `FileSearchResult` inherits from `SearchResult`, and that the type parameter only occurs in covariant positions in the interface)

Or if you'll always use `SearchResult`s' children:

```
interface ISearch<out T> where T : SearchResult { 
  // ...
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Now that I know you use the type parameter also in an input position, you could use a base non-generic interface:

```
interface ISearch { }
interface ISearch<T> : ISearch where T : SearchResult { }

// ...

public ISearch getSearchObject() { 
  return new FileSearch(); 
}
```

Or [segregate your interfaces (pdf)](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf) (if that makes sense for you):

```
interface ISearchCo<out T> where T : SearchResult {
  T Result { get; }
}
interface ISearchContra<in T> where T : SearchResult {
  T Result { set; }
}

// ...

public ISearchCo<SearchResult> getSearchObject() { 
  return (ISearchCo<SearchResult>)new FileSearch(); 
}
```

Comment: @jordao - I'm not sure what the 'out' gives me, but I'm setting the type of a accessor using T, which gives me `'T' must be invariantly valid. 'T' is covariant` as an error when I use 'out'

Comment: @jordao - Actually, I'm already doing that, `where T : SearchResult`, just thought it might be extraneous information

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Comment: @Brett: ahhh, that's a problem then.... `out` can only be used if the type parameters is used on output (covariant) position only.

Comment: @Jordao - Does that provide a reason for why I cannot return an implementation of the interface in my `getSearchObject()` method?

Comment: @Brett: The reason is that you cannot cast `FileSearch`, which is a `ISearch<FileSearchResult>`, to a `ISearch<SearchResult>`. I.e. without covariance, `ISearch<FileSearchResult>` is not `ISearch<SearchResult>`.

Comment: @Brett: You're better off using a base, non-generic interface then.